# Issues Using Dependency Injection with AccountController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unity-container, identity

I'm cleaning up and old app using MVC 5 EF,Identity, Unity I'm having trouble figuring out how to register the DI for the AccountController.  in the 
In the Below example I changed 
the Empty Constructor from the following

```
      public AccountController()
    { }
```

To this

```
public AccountController(IDateTimeService dateTimeService, ILeagueLogic leagueLogic)
{
    _dateTimeService = dateTimeService;
    _leagueLogic = leagueLogic;
}
```

So in the full Controller I have the Following

```
  public class AccountController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager;
    private IDateTimeService _dateTimeService;
    private ILeagueLogic _leagueLogic;

         [InjectionConstructor] <-- Nailed it
    public AccountController(IDateTimeService dateTimeService, ILeagueLogic leagueLogic)
    {
        _dateTimeService = dateTimeService;
        _leagueLogic = leagueLogic;
    }

    public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
    {
        UserManager = userManager;
        SignInManager = signInManager;
    }

    public ApplicationUserManager UserManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _userManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();
        }
        private set
        {
            _userManager = value;
        }
    }

  private ApplicationSignInManager _signInManager;
    public ApplicationSignInManager SignInManager
    {
        get
        {
            return _signInManager ?? HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Get<ApplicationSignInManager>();
        }
        private set { _signInManager = value; }
    }


    //
    // GET: /Account/Login
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }
```

}

In the UnityConfig File I have the following

```
 public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {

        container.RegisterType<IDateTimeService, DateTimeService>();
        container.RegisterType<ILeagueLogic, LeagueLogic>();


        container.RegisterType<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>, UserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        container.RegisterType<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        container.RegisterType<DbContext, ApplicationDbContext>();
        container.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>();
       // container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());  <-- Removed this line
    }
```

But I get

> The type MyProgram.Controllers.AccountController does not have a constructor that takes the parameters ().

Kinda Stumped.,. I belive I need to  Register the controller somehow not sure.. exactly how

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last line

`container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());`

[explicitly tells Unity](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882(v=pandp.20).aspx) to create an `AccountController` instance using the `new AccountController()` constructor

[Based on the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178463(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec12) the type registration should look like that:

```
    container.RegisterType<AccountController>(
               new InjectionConstructor(
                 container.Resolve< IDateTimeService>(), 
                 container.Resolve< IDateTimeService >()));
```

**UPD:** if you have just one constructor in your `AccountController` class, you may try to remove the `container.RegisterType<AccountController>(new InjectionConstructor());` line completely. Unity should be able to construct an instance without a hint.

**UPD2:**

In case you have more than one constructor, but only one is used to construct an instance by Unity (for example the second one might be used in unit-test project) you could decorate the new ctor with `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute

```
[InjectionConstructor]
public AccountController(IDateTimeService dateTimeService, ILeagueLogic leagueLogic)
{
    _dateTimeService = dateTimeService;
    _leagueLogic = leagueLogic;
}
```

Comment: I tried soemthing like that earlier and I get (dateTimeService, leagueLogic) don't exist in current Context.

Comment: oh, I see (haven't touched Unity for ages ;) ). Try removing the AccountController registration completely, no need for named arguments here (unless you have more than one constructor in your AccountController)

Comment: Theres 2 constructors. Maybe thats part of the issue.  I commented out the Original Constructor. `     //public AccountController(ApplicationUserManager userManager, ApplicationSignInManager signInManager)
        //{
        //    UserManager = userManager;
        //    SignInManager = signInManager;

        //}'

Comment: You can decorate the new one with `[InjectionConstructor]` attribute